# Error: Pip is not working

Tags: pip

i am typing pip install paramiko

bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python2: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Which python do you install on your Linux? python 3 or python 2?

for `python2` try:

```
python -m pip install paramiko
```

`python3`:

```
python3 -m pip install paramiko
```

Comment: i have both but there are programs that are runnig only in python2, doesn't matter i solved the problem